# NET Analyzers and AnalysisLevel confusion

Tags: roslyn-code-analysis

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#analysismode), when AnalysisMode is set to All, "All rules are enabled as build warnings". But what I am seeing is that some rules, like CA1014, CA1021 and CA1060 are still suppressed. Is there something I am missing in "All rules are enabled" statement?

Comment: Do you have an `.editorconfig` file and/or other related analysis properties in your `*.csproj` or `Directory.Build.props` files?

Comment: @Meligy, no .editorconfig, nothing special in the project file. See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/AnalysisLevel-latest-all-does-not-enable/10518317 for a sample project.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is by design: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/38348.